# Script tags for AngularJS + HTML not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, calendar

I've been working on this HTML calendar using AngularJS as well as Bootstrap, and the program seems to run but none of the scripts & links that I want it to use work.  I have all the bower components and what not downloaded already and the location for them is in those files exactly. I am very confused, please help!
[These are the scripts and links I am trying to use and can't seem to get any of them to work.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GFrP.png)

Comment: Hard to say what's wrong without seeing your folder structure, but my guess would be the references to the bower components may be off.

Comment: Start the reference with one "/" to have reference the root directory of your application.

Comment: Are they all loading in page? Check browser dev tools network. Are errors thrown in console? *"won't work"* isn't much of a problem description. Does any angular work?